# Full-page flexbox that doesn't grow beyond window size

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to make a page where the main portion of it is a canvas that should be scaled up, while keeping its aspect ratio, as much as it can to fill in the browser window. Above and below the canvas there would be other UI elements of fixed height.

With the following straightforward `flex`-column-containing-`flex`-row setup, I have most of this working:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.fullpage {
    height: 100vh;
}

.flexrow {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flexcol {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="fullpage flexcol">
      <h1 style="text-align: center">Foo</h1>
      <canvas width="320" height="200" style="background: red"></canvas>
      <div class="flexrow">
        <div>Bar</div>
        <div>Baz</div>
        <div>Quux</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when the browser window is too wide compared to the canvas's aspect ratio, this produces vertical overflow: the `Foo` header disappears and the `Bar` &c. line is only visible via scrolling.

How do I keep this nicely resizing/window-filling layout of the canvas while also disallowing the whole page to be larger than the window?

Comment: min-height:0 to canvas?

Comment: @TemaniAfif that breaks the canvas's aspect ratio when the window is too wide. The canvas should just be narrower than full window width in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer about it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden; /* Prevent vertical overflow */
      }

      #canvas-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100vh - 2em); /* Subtract the height of the header */
      }

      #canvas-container canvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0; margin-left: auto;
        right: 0; margin-right: auto;
        object-fit: contain; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
      }

      .header {
        text-align: center;
        height: 2em;
      }

      .flexrow {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 2em;
      }

      .flexrow > div {
        flex: 1;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Foo</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="canvas-container">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="200" style="background: red"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="flexrow">
      <div>Bar</div>
      <div>Baz</div>
      <div>Quux</div>
    </div>

    <script>
      const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

      function resizeCanvas() {
        const container = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
        const aspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
        const containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
        const containerHeight = container.offsetHeight;

        let canvasWidth, canvasHeight;

        if (containerWidth / containerHeight > aspectRatio) {
          canvasWidth = containerHeight * aspectRatio;
          canvasHeight = containerHeight;
        } else {
          canvasWidth = containerWidth;
          canvasHeight = containerWidth / aspectRatio;
        }

        canvas.style.width = `${canvasWidth}px`;
        canvas.style.height = `${canvasHeight}px`;
      }

      window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
      resizeCanvas(); // Call once on page load
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this one helps you.

Comment: Have you actually tried out your suggestion? It doesn't fix the problem with wide windows; in fact, I don't see any change at all.

Comment: Sorry I just update it, can you check it again?

Comment: I'm accepting this because, well, it does solve my issue. However, I really wish there was a pure CSS version. And even more important would be the ability to avoid the hard-coding of the non-canvas sizes in the `calc(100vh - 2em)` calculation. I am once again deeply disappointed in CSS...